# What does it mean to "bow reversely"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

In a short story I am reading, demons are "bowing reversely" (in the presence of the Devil himself). What does it mean?

> Bowing reversely, Gorson, Goap, Zimimar and Amaimon, lords of the four
> quarters, went out one after one, leaving their prince alone.

Comment: Can you provide the quote with some context?

Comment: @StephenS Done, but there is nothing else than that.

Comment: [Here's the book/story](https://books.google.com/books?id=UKdagAGVeOAC&pg=PP6&lpg=PP6&dq=%22bowing+reversely%22&source=bl&ots=yV7cNNTDDH&sig=ACfU3U17_ruLe98Yfl8e2HbQ3wBExZRE4A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj50uvJgdrrAhVRExoKHYfeDzsQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bowing%20reversely%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very odd expression, but I would take it as meaning they bowed while walking backward out of the room.

I’m not sure how widespread it is/was, but in some cultures, it is/was considered rude to turn your back on the monarch. So, people would have to walk backward to leave a room if the monarch was there. Protocol also required bowing to the monarch before speaking and after being dismissed, usually just once, but some could take that a little further to require it while walking in and out.